# Handle multiple user profile types in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to properly configure an Orchard website for multiple types of user registration.

My site has 2 user types; customer and employee. I can add all fields to the User Content Type, which would work fine, but I can't seem to find a possible way to have separate User Registration forms, views, ...

I have thought about using Dynamic Forms, and create a form for employees and a form for customers, and use the input of these forms for the creation of users through workflows.

This does feel like an awful lot of overhead for the creation of 2 different user types and has some limitations (there is no support for image upload in Dynamic Forms).

Basically my question is: what is the proper way in Orchard CMS to handle this and have multiple types of users (and user registration forms)?

Comment: There is only one type of user in Orchard, but you can differentiate using roles.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with *dynamic* content parts (remember, a user is a content in Orchard):

[How to dynamically add a content part in a Orchard content handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30397197/3936440)

With the linked solution you can write:

```
IUser lUser = ...;

ICustomer lCustomer = lUser.As<ICustomer>();
if (lCustomer != null) ...

IEmployee lEmployee = lUser.As<IEmployee>();
if (lEmployee != null) ...
```

If you do not know what content parts are, have a look at the official documentation first:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part

Comment: Although this is a nice solution, I do think it should be possible to do this in a CMS without the use of custom code...

Comment: @Arsenal The code from my answer only shows you how to distinguish the user in code. Regarding your separate forms issue, you should be able to display separate forms by using the placement.info functionality as you now have different parts attached to a user, but i'm not fully sure as i never used that extensivly: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info